# There appears to be mismatch in clang-llvm ver 11.0.0 python bindings

Tags: python, c++, clang

I use clang's PYTHON bindings for my work in which I have to walk the AST of C++ programs. I recently tried to switch to release 11.0.0, and noticed that in my generated AST node type for

```
Foo *foo = new Foo();
```

was not showing

```
CursorKind.CXX_NEW_EXPR = CursorKind(134)
```

but as

```
CursorKind.CXX_DELETE_EXPR = CursorKind(135)
```

My searching led me to this mismatch in header file/bindings file in LLVM-11.0.0.

```
# Numbers match in rel 10.0.1
llvm-project-10.0.1
clang/include/clang-c/Index.h:  CXCursor_CXXNewExpr                    = 134,
clang/bindings/python/clang/cindex.py:CursorKind.CXX_NEW_EXPR = CursorKind(134)


# Numbers do not match in rel 11.0.0
llvm-project-11.0.0         
clang/include/clang-c/Index.h:  CXCursor_CXXNewExpr = 135,                 
clang/bindings/python/clang/cindex.py:CursorKind.CXX_NEW_EXPR = CursorKind(134)
```

I am new to CLANG-LLVM world have sent an email as directed to obtain a bugzilla account. However I have had no response. My question, would anyone else agree that this numbers mismatch could be an issue?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/clang/c/_h_OGuC7q7k

I asked the same question to a google group for clang and there I received a comment/acknowledgement of this issue.